# Is there a way to specify TLS 1.0 for one WCF Call and TLS 1.2 for another WCF or WebClient call within a single application?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have an application that needs to call multiple web services.
One web services only works with TLS 1.0.
Another has TLS 1.0 disabled.

Is there a way to specify which TLS version you would like used on each WCF Web Service call?

I'm able to use

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

But it seems to force this setting across the board.

.net 4.5.2

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace SSLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                Test();
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                Test();

            }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }


        static void Test()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile("https://webservices2.autotask.net/atservices/1.5/atws.wsdl", @"c:\code\test.wsdl");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Tls12
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secur
e channel.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at SSLTest.Program.Test() in c:\code\sandbox\SSLTest\SSLTest\SSLTest\Program.
cs:line 28
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
Tls12
Tls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple security protocols like so:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me! It properly negotiated the right TLS version once I specified multiple protocols.